# How to get Select2 configuration programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have in a page several `<SELECT>` that are bound to `Select2` with Ajax datasource.

I was trying to find a way to get the `url` parameter that was used when the `Select2` was bound.

```
 obj.select2({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        allowClear: true,
        language: "es",
        width: '100%',
        ajax: {
            url: url    <----- this is the setting I need to get
        }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `obj.data("select2").options.options.ajax.url`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

See https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

AJAX result must using data format:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

(or you can transforming result data, see docs)

In your HTML:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>
```

In your Javascript:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
    dataType: 'json'
  }
});
```

Comment: As I understand what OP is requesting, they want to *retrieve* that value of ajax.url (ie `"https://api.github.com/search/repositories"` in your example) - *after* the `.select2({ajax:{url:"..."}});` then get that url.

Comment: @freedomn-m right!

Comment: i dunno, something like `<select class="js-data-example-ajax" data-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories"></select>` and `url: $('.js-data-example-ajax').data('url')`?

Comment: @PeterNovotníček when the `Select2` was built using options in the constructor instead of `data-*` attributes, that is not possible. Thanks anyway.